# Using saripaar in DialogFragment

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

I want use saripaar in `DialogFragment`.

**consider this code:**

```
builder.setView(view);
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
Button register_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_register_send_data);
register_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendData(v);
    }
});
validator = new Validator(this);
validator.setValidationListener(this);
```

When I want to validate I get this code:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No rules found. You must have at least one rule to validate.` If you are using custom annotations
And this my Xml Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/txt_register_name"
                  android:hint="@string/name"
                />
        <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/txt_register_family"
                  android:hint="@string/family"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txt_register_email"
              android:hint="@string/email"
            />
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txt_register_password"
              android:hint="@string/password"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:inputType="textPassword"
            />
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txt_register_confirm_password"
              android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:inputType="textPassword"
            />
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_register_send_data" android:text="@string/send_info"/>
```

Is there any relation between my layout and my class?
What is my problem?

Comment: Can you post your XML code along with a screenshot?

Comment: @RagunathJawahar I update my question

Comment: @user2464315 Where are your rules defined?

Comment: did you solve this ? i have same issue